# Appium 1.6.4 Touchaction issue

Tags: ubuntu, automation, appium

I upgraded Appium to 1.6.4 and now I got:

```
  KeyError: 'touchAction'
```

in my testautomation for Android device. 
Before that it worked smoothly.

```
  I am using Ubuntu 16.04
  I am using Selenium v3.0.1 (btw Selenium v3.4.1 - the latest one, refuses to work with my Android test automation)
```

Any ideas how to fix that?
My code is:

```
def panic(self, wait=5):
    action = TouchAction(self.driver)
    panic =  self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.eightdevelopment.eas.android:id/panicText')
    action.long_press(panic).perform().wait(wait).release().perform().wait(wait)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem is with the perform() method.The perform() method performs a chain of actions on the driver.It is supposed to be used at the end of the touchaction.